# Conversion from "id" to "resourceName" for GoogleContactEntry to Person

Tags: google-people-api

I have already stored google contact entries in my local database. I am migrating my code from [contacts api](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3) to [people api](https://developers.google.com/people). To retrieve a [single contact](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3#retrieving_a_single_contact) in contacts api {id} was required. But in case of [people-api](https://developers.google.com/people) it is needed to pass "resourceName(eg:people/c2134122417240780462)" in request path to fetch [single contact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).

But as I have already stored ids in my local, how can I get resourceName using Id(stored locally) to perform update/delete operations?

Comment: I don't think you can use `contactId` to retrieve a person in People API via `people/{account_id}`. Both refer to different `ids`. But if you'd give more detailed information on what you want to accomplish, maybe a workaround could be found.

Comment: In case there is some update on any contacts in my local, _I want to replay same update on Google using updateContact api_. But the problem here is that I have _id_  already with me,  but people api needs `resourceId` to be passed which can only be retrieved using `connections` api.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of storing your google Contacts in a local database?

Comment: It's for display purpose. Contacts listing here is a part of well established app. So this feature can not be changed now.
This is something which is of very higher priority here. So we store the contacts in local database for user and show it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use another property (shared by Contacts and People) instead of `contactId`. Maybe `phoneNumber` and/or `nickname`?

Comment: Sure. Thanks @iamblichus for all the help

Comment: So is the proposed workaround valid for you? If that's the case, would you consider posting an answer explaining what you did?

Comment: In my case I will be maintaining a local Map of contactId vs resourceName. I can fetch resourceName by contactid using this map and use it for update/delete/fetch operation.